# How to split a string at a specific character but not replace that character?

Tags: php, regex, laravel, string, split

I want to split at every ';' and every '{' from the string below:

```
// string
$str = 'abc;def;ghi{jkl;}if('mno') {pqr;}';
// expression
$pattern = "/[;{\(]/";

$result = preg_split($pattern);

print_r($result);
```

It splits at the point of every ';' and '{' but these characters are also removed which I don't want. I used explode() function though it splits, but also replace that character.

And how to multiple splitting in a string?

expected result should look like that.
array (

```
0 => "abc;",

1 => "def;",

2 => "ghi{",

3 => "jkl;",

4 => "}if('mno') {",

5 => "pqr;",

6 => "}",
)
```

Please guide me thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Example:

```
// string
$str = "abc;def;ghi{jkl;}if('mno') {pqr;}";
// expression
$pattern = "/(?=[;{\(])/";

$result = preg_split($pattern, $str);
```

$result is a array like

```
array (
  0 => "abc",
  1 => ";def",
  2 => ";ghi",
  3 => "{jkl",
  4 => ";}if",
  5 => "('mno') ",
  6 => "{pqr",
  7 => ";}",
)
```

Comment: I want as 0 => "abc;", ... and 2 = "ghi{",

Comment: see the expected result please.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern actually solved my problem.

```
$pattern = "/(?<=[;{}])/";
```

I'm accepting answering because @jspit helped me to solve it.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to accept an answer that doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using a lookbehind with your character class will take 127 steps on your sample string.

By removing the lookbehind, and simply releasing the matched characters with `\K`, the regex engine parses the string in just 55 steps.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OfKu3))

```
var_export(
    preg_split('/[;{}]\K/', $str)
);
```

If you don't want empty elements:

```
var_export(
    preg_split('/[;{}]\K/', $str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```